# Errno 98 (Address already in use) Python Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting an error: [Errno 98] Address already in use while trying to stream video through port. Is there a ctrl-alt-delete method to close the port on linux. Our video stream stops right away.

Answer (score 0):

The socket is probably stuck in a TIME_WAIT state.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858817/66349