# Bind error 98 "Address in use" persists after application killed

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, bind

And I cannot start a new instance of the application I am debugging for a few minutes after it was killed or SEGFAULT-ed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Binding Socket: "Address already in use"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380057/python-binding-socket-address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set `REUSEADDR` for the socket:

E.g. in Python.

`socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`

Please add more info to your question. What programming language do you use? Show some example code or error output.

Have a look at this post for a more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380198/1668622

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the operating system doesn't free a socket immediately after an application crashes and I need to set the reuse flag. There seems to be some sort of a timeout for that in linux?