# How to remove the socket server from "busy" state after `kill PID`?

Tags: python, sockets, http, terminal, time-wait

I have a simple socket server set-up to send some numbers to a client in the intranet. While testing, I stop the `server.py` script from terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) which later causes busy server error in Safari when I try to reach the same page.

I saw this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait/329851#329851) But the issues are:

1. I could not find the `/etc/init.d/networking restart` file. I am using Mac and this is for Linux. Also it is an overkill for every-time I test my server. At least 10 times an hour.
2. Inserting the option `SO_REUSEADDR` in the code did help `Address already in use` but I reckon that my server is up but is in a busy state. Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380198), I had edited the **code** to this:

```
host = <my machine address>  
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
port = 8080
s.bind((host, port))
```

**What changes do I make on my server to remove this error in Safari?**

> **Safari** can’t open the page "my-ip" because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes and then try again.

Output of `lsof -i:8080`, after stopping the script was

```
python3.7 11881 <user>    3u  IPv4 <Device>   0t0  TCP <my machine address>?:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

I did `kill 11881` and then re-run the code but got the same message in Safari.

Output of `netstat -na | grep "8080"` was

```
tcp4       0      0  <my machine address>.8080     *.*    LISTEN
```

while the script was running and nothing when I `KeyboardInterrupt` it.

**Firefox** shows the page momentarily and then shows the error page

> The connection was reset

**Chrome** shows an empty page only.

**Update:** It works in python 2.7 but not in 3.5. The difference in the code comes at:

```
c.send('\n')
```

in 2.7 and

```
c.send(bytes('\n'.encode('utf-8')))
```

in 3.5 where

`c` is

```
c, (client_host, client_port) = s.accept()
```

Rest is all the same.

Comment: The file name `/etc/init.d/networking` is completely specified; it points to a file named `networking` in the `init.d` directory in the `etc` directory in the root directory. However, it is distro-specific (probably Debian) so if you are on a different platform, you need to find out how to restart networking services on your system. (This is probably overkill in this situation, though.)

Comment: @tripleee yes it a platform issue, I'll include it in my question. Also that is really an overkill as visible in the comments here: https://serverfault.com/a/329846

Comment: @barmar  I have edited the question to include why this is different. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says in the duplicate? My money is on "still a duplicate" even if the symptoms are different.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284251/how-to-restart-network-services-on-sierra Is my third topmost Google hit for "macos restart network" (the top two were specifically about wifi).

Comment: I edited the code as I said. Not other things. Can you specify which one in particular?

Comment: My recollection is that you get an error every second time with `SO_REUSE` but this might have been on Linux. In this case, the slightly dismal but manageable workaround is to try twice.

Comment: Why do you think this is different? The "address already in use" error happens on the server, not the client; the client error message is a separate symptom of the same problem.

Comment: The `en0` answer only wrks for the interface with that name; there is no way to know just from that name if that's a wifi interface or not. There are other answers which shut down all interfaces; or just repeat for every interface you want to reset.

Comment: @tripleee Using `ifconfig` revelas 8-9 names. Do I need to reset them all?

Comment: Probably not; some are probably specific to Docker and some might be present but not up. In fact just the one which your program is connecting to should be sufficient I guess.

Comment: (Not in a place where chat is convenient.)

Comment: @tripleee it is wifi then. I reset it and it didnt work.

Comment: @Barmar
it doesn't work, for one . 
the output in the terminal is different and are in two different stages of a server setup, for two. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195590/discussion-between-ankiiiiiii-and-tripleee).

Comment: I've reopened the question. You did ask where you're supposed to put the `SO_REUSEADDR` option, so it seemed like that question answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accidentally commented out a line

```
c.recv(1000)
```

Where `c` is mentioned in the question.

I found it when I compared this to an older version of the same file.