# socket.SO_REUSEADDR still puts connection on TIME_WAIT

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sockets

I'm trying to implement a simple example of a distributed producer consumer, and while testing, I always get the following error:

> OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Even though many posts claim that `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before bind would allow me to ignore the TIME_WAIT, I still get the same exception when trying to connect for a second time.

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('', 4330))
s.listen()

s.accept()
s.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('', 4334))

s.connect((myaddress, 4330))
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When client socket closed locally, if you try to connect to the **same destination** again, with recreated socket of same ip:port, `TIME_WAIT` will be in effect, regardless of `SO_REUSEADDR`.

To avoid this, you can make the server to initiate `close()` first.

Please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380057/python-binding-socket-address-already-in-use#answer-19247688) and [this article](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/Tech/addrinuse.html) for more details.